# How to bulk shift product id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, migration

Due to migration collision, I need to shift upward many product IDs.

*Here is why :*

*If I use a delta migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2, new products in Magento 2, which have the same id than new products in Magento 1, are overwritten.*

Is it safe to do such an id shift with SQL ?

Is there somewhere the full list of tables to update ?